# Replace a 'bel' character in a file in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, ssis, replace, hex

I've come across a character in one of my data feeds, which I have never encountered before

[image: This is how it looks in Notepad++ view]

[image: This is how it looks in Notepad view]

The images above are the data feed in Notepad++ and Notepad view. As you can see it appears as 'BEL' in Notepad++ and a sort of 'bullet point' in Notepad.

How would I go about replacing this character in vb.NET?

I've tried a simple replace in a SSIS Script Task by copying and pasting the character into the replace function, e.g.

text = text.Replace("copy and pasted character", "")

and this gives this error

[image: SSIS error]

All help is extremely appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve got no idea what SSIS is but since you wanted to know a solution in VB.NET, the code you’ve tried will work here. That is:

```
text = text.Replace("copy and pasted character", "")
```

will work just fine in VB. Alternatively, you can use the following:

```
text = text.Replace(Chr(7).ToString(), "")
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the speedy response. It is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Find out what the Ascii value of the character is and then use the Chr function to eliminate it

i.e.

```
text = text.Replace(Chr(n), "")
```

[Bell] is probably character 7

Comment: Won’t compile with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Erm, yes it will....

    Option Strict On

    Module Module1

        Sub Main()

            Dim test As String

            test = "testing A ..."

            test = test.Replace(Chr(65), "zap")

            Console.WriteLine(test)

        End Sub

    End Module

Compiles just fine

Comment: You’re right. Grr, I hate the MSDN. It simply doesn’t list the implicit conversion of `char` to `string`. (Also, that’s a stupid conversion, it shouldn’t exist. A `char` is not a `string`. Period.)